# How to follow someone else's Stack Exchange (questions) filter

Tags: support, tag-filters

The [ANTLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR)-interest list [is shutting down](http://www.antlr.org/support.html) and [Ter](http://www.antlr.org/) has decided to use both Stack Overflow for questions and Google groups dicussions for ANTLR users. There seems to be problems with new Stack Overflow users trying to effectively monitor the ANTLR tags.

I created a [new filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/70326/antlr-interest) for just the ANTLR tags, but how do I allow others to follow it? Do I just give the link as I did here?

(I would not be surprised if this is a duplicate, I just could not find the original.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can just give them the link to the filter you created.  Note also that there's an [Antlr interest](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/70326/antlr-interest?sort=active) RSS link at the bottom of that page that you can direct users to.  It will give them the same questions as your filter in their RSS reader.