# What does "users following" display at question filters?

Tags: discussion

In the "Filtered questions" tab at the stats there are "users following" displayed. I would think this shows how much users have this filter in there list. Does that mean i can "subscribe" or add someones filter to my own?

Comment: I think the "users following" just means that x users have that tag in their "favorite tags" list.  Doesn't have anything to do with your non-ability to "subscribe" to some person's filter.

Comment: That is what i thought, but why add a stat like that, it is pretty much coincidence to have the exact same tag filter list. Unless you could add someones filter.

Comment: I don't know how you are mentally connecting those two things.  The number is simply an arbitrary metric of tag popularity.

Comment: I am not talking about tags, i'm talking about tag filters. Look at one of your filters on SE. Selecting one gives you stats on the right below the filter select section. This is NOT tag popularity but filter popularity. Like i said, it is pretty much coincidence to have the exact same filters as someone. Since it is a pretty useless stat my mental state drifts off.

Comment: No @MartijnPieters i'm talking about the "TAG FILTERS". http://stackexchange.com/filters/117000/web-dev. As you can see nobody seems to be interested in the most popular web development tags. I cannot imagine 1% of the users setting up the same filter by coincidence.

Comment: Well, there is a button on that page that says "Save to My Filters."

Comment: Well, we discovered something now didn't we? Since it is my tag filter i cannot add it. So where can i find popular filter sets?

Comment: How did you find the web-dev one?

Comment: I created it... :D

Comment: I'm asking in the Teacher's Lounge.  Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok thanks, but my mind goes into a mental drift again and making up you do not use filters. How can you make sense of the 100's of questions coming in every minute over the SE network?

Comment: I have my hands full with just Stack Overflow and Programmers.

Comment: Apparently you share your filter with others, via a link, and they can then subscribe.  There doesn't appear to be a list of other people's filters, and if there was, it would be very long; the ID of your filter suggests that there are 116,999 filters created before yours.  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158722

Comment: Time for another question i guess, or rather a feature request. Since the filters already stored in the database it cannot be that hard to output the most popular or filter these by some tags. Would be a somewhat usefull feature don't you think? Although filters are personal it saves time to pickup a popular one and edit it.

Comment: I don't think it would be useful, no.  Filters are highly-specific to the individual creating them.  Only a small percentage of them would be interesting to anyone else.

Comment: Then back to this question, what is the use of the stat? It really does not show much. Are there filters that are being used by many users, you just pointed out thats not the case. So why add a stat option like that?

Comment: Probably because it's logically consistent with favorited tags having a similar stat.  You're certainly free to promote the tag filter yourself.

Comment: It is nice to know how popular a tag is sometimes, like when asking a question. Do you think this filter popularity is handy on it's own? I do not think so.

Comment: Well, it's not impossible to find others' filters. Changing the filter link, I got [the very first filter created](http://stackexchange.com/filters/1/) =P